# How to prevent a macro from being imported from a library?

Tags: macros

To give more context, I am trying to override the `\state` macro from cryptocode as it conflicts with the `\state` under affiliations. Unfortunately, I extensive use the other macros from `cryptocode`. Thus, I cannot skip using `cryptocode`. Here is a sample code:

```
\documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}

\title{The Name of the Title Is Hope}

\usepackage[n,advantage,operators,sets,adversary,landau,probability,notions,logic,ff,mm,primitives,events,complexity,asymptotics,keys]{cryptocode}

\author{Huifen Chan}
\affiliation{%
    \institution{Tsinghua University}
    \city{Haidian Qu}
    \state{Beijing Shi}
    \country{China}
}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Is there a way to prevent importing a macro from a library?

Comment: No and yes.  You can use `\let\oldstate=\state` before loading the package, then use `\let\state=\oldstate` after.  The question is if the package uses `\state` internally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The macro `\state` is one of the main ones in `cryptocode`. On the other hand, `\state` is used by `acmart` only when processing the title block.

We can juggle between the two meanings, restoring the one of `cryptocode` after executing `\maketitle`.

Unfortunately, `cryptocode` abuses `\def`, so it's difficult to find out other possible incompatibilities.

```
\documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}

% save a copy of \state as defined by acmart
\NewCommandCopy{\acmstate}{\state}
% undefine \state for safety
\let\state\relax

\usepackage[
  n,
  advantage,
  operators,
  sets,
  adversary,
  landau,
  probability,
  notions,
  logic,
  ff,
  mm,
  primitives,
  events,
  complexity,
  asymptotics,
  keys,
]{cryptocode}

% cryptocode redefines \state, save its meaning
\NewCommandCopy{\cryptocodestate}{\state}
% restore acmart's \state
\RenewCommandCopy{\state}{\acmstate}

\title{The Name of the Title Is Hope}

\author{Huifen Chan}
\affiliation{%
    \institution{Tsinghua University}
    \city{Haidian Qu}
    \state{Beijing Shi}
    \country{China}
}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
% restore cryptocode's \state
\RenewCommandCopy{\state}{\cryptocodestate}

\end{document}
```